# How to move objects using other object transformation?

Tags: geometry-nodes

[image]

I want the sphere to transform the objects which are parallel to sphere's normal. Suppose the sphere is a hand and those are the pages when hand come to drab a top most page other nearest pages will also transform a little bit. Thanks in advance

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you please tell us how the pages should transform? move on z-axis or how? maybe you can add a link to an animation how it should look like?

Answer (score 1):

if this is what you wanna achieve:

[image]

...then you made already a lot right:

I just added some additional nodes, to make the animation smoother:

[image]

i moved the realize instances before the output node, so that i could apply a different material per sheet. And i hoped you want to move the sheets as "one" piece, not vertices, right?

Comment: This works great. Thank you but I'm looking for this kind of thing. 

[![enter image description here][1]][1]
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OfuDd.gif

Comment: i wished you would have added that gif to your question earlier....but tbh - if you understood my node tree, you should be able to transfer that knowledge and do that animation on your own now. If not, please tell us what exactly your problem is now. thx.